# How to get intervals of hist() function in r?

Tags: r, histogram, intervals

How do you get "intervals" (not bins) from `hist()`?

If I run `hist(VARIABLE,seq(0,30,by=3)`. The idea is to get a vector like this :

```
(0,3]
(3,6]
...
```

I know I can get it by this command :

```
unique(cut(VARIABLE,seq(0,30,by=3))
```

But it looks like very unefficient since we have to generate this long length vector first.

Comment: Save it (hist command result) into a variable and take a look a the structure. You'll get $breaks in the result. Intervals are then break1 to break2, etc.

Comment: yeah I know that, but i don't want the bins, i want the intervals

Comment: You are joking, right? Intervals are between the breaks. If you know all the breaks, you know all the intervals. You have to add like one or two lines of code to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I wanted. Here it is :

```
levels(cut(VARIABLE,breaks=hist(VARIABLE,seq(0,230,by=3))$breaks))
```